# List Clusters using SQL

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB [manual](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Tutorial-Clusters.html) shows how to obtain CLUSTER information using the console.
For example, to obtain a list of Clusters, i would do:

```
orientdb> LIST CLUSTERS
```

But, i cannot find how to obtain the same information using SQL.

**Is there a way to obtain a list of all the Clusters using SQL?**

(I'm using OrientDB 2.2.29).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
select name as NAME, clusterIds as ID from (select expand(classes) from metadata:schema)
```

Comment: This gives me the ClassName, and the "assigned" ClusterIDs. Is there a way to obtain not the ClusterIDs, but the Cluster names?